# HTML+CSS template, please explain

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Can someone explain how to create html+css template responsive. Like in this image. Mby some generator or something. I don't know anything about css or html. I just need this template for my to do list in this summer.

http://postimg.org/image/70vjuu013/

P.s. - The grey sidebars are backgroung image.

Thanks for any help, Gurkis.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: " I don't know anything about css or html." - now would be a great time to start researching it by yourself then :)

Comment: I agree with enigma. If you don't know anything about HTML or CSS you need to learn that before worrying about making a responsive template. The best resource I ;know of to get started is W3Schools. Google them, it should be your first result.

Comment: A) Do the HTML and CSS tutorials / activities on W3Schools. B) Look into CSS media queries. C) ??? D) Profit.

Answer (score 0):

Learning HTML and CSS is a long process, which has to pass over experimenting, failing, trying, searching ...

I don't like to recommand links, but you should look for a tutorial, what you are trying to do is quite simple and should take you few hours. I don't think it would make sense for use to give you an already working solution if you do not understand how to use it :D

I personally liked [open classroom HTML5 CSS3 tutorial](http://openclassrooms.com/courses/build-your-website-with-html5-and-css3) because it is free and quite accessible but one more time, there is many alternative feel free to google such ressource.

You will probably love it at the beginning, then hate it because of limitation, then pass it and love it again so good luck and don't loose faith :D

Comment: _experimenting, failing, trying_ Hehe had a good giggle at this.

Answer (score 0):

This will help get you started. You will need to add more, but this will show you some fundamentals and you can plug and play around with it to learn as you go. This isn't a site for people to build code for you, but to better understand what you are doing.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="red_background">
        <div class="text">
            <p>Red</p>
        </div
    </div>
    <div class="blue_background">
        <div class="text">
            <p>Blue</p>
        </div
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.red_background (
width: 100%;
background-color: red;
}

.blue_background {
width: 100%;
background-color: blue;
}

.text {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
}
```